# Computing rotating pairs

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to develop an algorithm that my software development team can use to pair off for daily stand-up calls. Each dev should be paired with every other dev before there is a repeat. In other words, the dev who is "most stale" for any given dev should be their next partner. If there are an odd number of devs, a rotating dev should get the day off. That position should rotate among all devs such that the next dev to have the day off last had the day off longer ago than any other dev.

I'm normally pretty good at this kind of thing, and I thought this would be fairly easy, but I've actually been struggling with it pretty hard.

Algorithms I've tried and why they don't work (roughly in temporal order/decreasing naivety). Note that I've largly ignored the odd-number-of-devs part of the problem in the explanations below, to keep things short-ish:

- Rotate the list of devs by the number of work days that have passed since the magic start day. Split the list in half and pair the two halves with each other by indexes (index 0 to 0, ...). This always pairs the same devs with each other (so obvious now, ****facepalm****).
- Duplicate the list of devs (visualize one above the other). Rotate one list by the number of days that have passed. Pair by indexes. This doesn't work because A may be paired with B while C is paired with A.
- Split the list of devs in half, rotate one half as above. This doesn't work because the halves never mix, some devs are never paired with other devs.
- Rotate the list of devs by the number of days that have passed. Pair the dev at index 0 with the dev in the last index. Pair the dev at index 1 with the dev in the second to last index. This doesn't work because pairs repeat after len/2 cycles.
- Make a copy of the list of devs (again, visualize one over the other). Rotate one of the lists by the number of days that have passed. Start forming pairs at one end of the list, matching indexes. If you're about to form a pair that contains a dev who is already in a valid pair, mark that potential pair as invalid and continue. This doesn't work because of situations like this[1].
- I tried messing around with patterns in a len(devs) by len(devs) grid, but it would be pretty hard to describe what I did here. Suffice it to say that I didn't find an algorithmic way to do this.
- I tried using a "picking dev"/"picked dev" strategy to avoid the A paired with B and C paired with A class of problems. For every dev in the list, compute a resulting key:value structure such that they are paired with the dev at index `day_diff % (len(devs) - 1) + 1` (call this `rotate_by`). The -1/+1 bit is to make sure they aren't paired with their self. For every dev at an even number index, their final, resulting pair is the dev they point at in the structure above ("picking devs"). For every dev at an odd number index, their resulting pair is the dev pointing at them in the structure above ("picked dev"). This doesn't work because if `rotate_by` is even, a "picking dev" will point at a "picking dev" will point at a "picking dev", so A will be paired with B who is paired with C.

This feels like it has to be a well-known and solved problem, but googling has been fruitless. Links/strategies would be greatly appreciated! As a side note, this seems like it would be an awesome interview question (easy to understand problem with obvious-seeming solutions that aren't right).

[1]

      `x  x  x  x
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: Off-topic, but have you considered a quality "randomized" algorithm? You might not get the perfect behavior you're looking for, but I bet you could get reasonably close with a simple "pair people off randomly". You could even weight the pairing probability by the number of days since a particular person was paired with another without *requiring* that all such constraints be met.

Comment: I have thought about that (in moments when I was super-sick of failing at this), as it would be very easy to implement. I didn't think about the weight bit you mentioned, however. Good thought. Frankly, I'm pretty determined to find an optimal solution, not to resort to randomness.

Comment: This is still an open problem that I'm actively working to solve.